# Apache sort order and preventing merging using the location directives in virtual server

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have two locations, one of which is a subset of the other. I would like the match to be either/or. However, in the more specific path, it appears to match both and merge the potential weblogic destinations. The desired behavior is it it matches /alpha/beta to go to location X. If it doesn't match /alpha/beta, but still has the root of /alpha to go to location Y.

```
<VirtualHost *:10000>
  ServerAdmin root@localhost
  Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks -Includes -Multiviews -IncludesNoExec -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  ServerName test-ws.amberroad.com

  <IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    DebugConfigInfo OFF
    Idempotent OFF
    KeepAliveEnabled ON
    WLIOTimeoutSecs 720
    ConnectTimeoutSecs 720
    WLSocketTimeoutSecs 720
    ConnectRetrySecs 0
  </IfModule>

  <Location /alpha>
    WLSRequest On
    WebLogicHost 10.10.10.10
    WebLogicPort 10002
  </Location>

  <Location /alpha/beta >
    WLSRequest On
    WebLogicCluster 10.10.10.10:10001,10.10.10.10:10000
  </Location>

  ErrorLog "|/opt/freeware/sbin/rotatelogs /wslog/error_log.10000_%a 86400"
  CustomLog "|/opt/freeware/sbin/rotatelogs /wslog/access_log.10000_%a 86400" common

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: HI @Slodog - have you tried putting /alpha/beta before /alpha - so it's dealt with first??

Comment: Thanks Gerard. I did try switching order, both before and after your suggestion. At least with a graceful restart, I don't see any change in behavior.

Comment: What do the access and error logs show?

Comment: On the proxy server error log, I see one occurene of the following today:

[Mon Jun 21 03:48:16.353751 2021] [weblogic:error] [pid 26084154:tid 6940] [client 192.168.231.101:16353] ap_proxy: trying POST /alpha/beta at backend host 10.10.10.10/10002; got exception 'Backend Server not responding'; state: reading status line or response headers from WLS (wrote? Y read? N); not failing over.

On the application server access logs from today, I am not seeing any /alpha/beta being directed to port 10000 or port 10001. All traffic is currently being directed to port 10002.

Comment: The above behavior occurs with /alpha/beta preceading /alpha in the list of locations.